# Wrong blast results

Tags: blastn, windows

I'm sorry if this is a naive question, but I get an odd thing going on.
I'm performing blast remotely in this way:

```
'blastn -task megablast -outfmt "6 std ssciname" -reward 1 -penalty -3  -db nt_v5 -max_target_seqs 100 -word_size 22 -query ' + final_file + " -taxidlist " + Plants_DB + " -out " + blastfile
```

However, when I see my remote results, I get a species whose seqid gives me *Vaccinium oxycoccos*. And when I put this seqid in blast online, the species is totally different.

(With this blast command, I perform a blast search against a specific list of IDS.)

How can this happen?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the parameters including word size and database, as well as all default settings are identical?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by seqid? Species have taxid, e.g. humans are 9606. Whereas genbank files have accession numbers (and formerly gi numbers).

Comment: @MatteoFerla I have this result, 4F703:00578:02013 KX677575.1 100.000 320 0 0 1 320 700 381 3.25e-165 592 Vaccinium oxycoccos and when I put the second result in blast I get a different specie...

Comment: @MichaeG. I tried to specify the most part with this commands: blastn -task megablast -word_size 28 -reward 1 -penalty -2 -outfmt 6 std ssciname -db nt_v5 -max_target_seqs 100 -query input.fasta -taxidlist test_ID_plants.ids -out blastfile.txt... do you think there is a problem with my nt database?

Comment: what do you mean with remotely? because in your command you are not using the `--remote` option, and there is an extra single quotation mark as well.

Comment: @zorbax, you don't need the option remote necessarily. also, what do you mean by "extra single quotation mark"

Comment: I assume that you call "remotely" because you are running your process in a remote computer. But the `-remote` option in blast means remote service at the NCBI servers, otherwise you are using a local version of nt database called nt_v5.

Comment: If I add the remote option to my inital command, the result continues to be wrong...